# Instantiate UIViewController Displaying UIImageView

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

not sure why this is so difficult for me, but I've been trying for days to create a simple app that has two UIViewControllers. The root view controller contains approximately 20 jpg thumbnail images. When selecting the image, I would like to instantiate a new UIViewController which displays the image that was selected. Would anyone happen to have any code for me to use? In the root view controller, I am open to using either UIImageViews or UIButtons with the background set to the respective jpg files.

My problem seems to be twofold: 1) determining which thumbnail image was selected and 2) instantiating the new UIViewController displaying the selected image.

Any advice and/or code would be greatly appreciated as I've been working tirelessly to solve what to most of you is probably a very simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add tap gesture to each imageView, in the selector method of tapGesture, you can extract the imageView who got tapped. Dont forget to set the userInteractionEnabled to YES for imageViews.

```
//code for adding tap gesture, where img is your imageView
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
        [img addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [img setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


//in selector method

-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecozgnizer *)recognizer
{

UIImageView *imView = (UIImageView *)recognizer.view;

SecondViewController *vc = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];

[vc setImage : imView.image];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];


}
```